# How to read in data structures from file in Erlang?

Tags: data-structures, io, erlang, readfile

I am going through an exercise that requires me to continually reuse data structures in Erlang when testing my applications and its getting a bit laborious. Saving them is easy enough with

```
file:write_file(Path, Data).
```

However I am struggling to read the data back in, the read_file and read_lines seem to make things unnecessarily complicated and not through lack of searching, I haven't found a good way to ready the structure back in to Erlang, although I have seen some extensive CSV and XML parsers. I feel there must be an easy way but I don't know the terminology. So far I have:

```
parse(Filename) ->
  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(Filename),
  binary:split(Data, [<<"\n">>], [global]).
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re right, there is an easy way:

```
file:consult(“../filepath/file.txt”).
```

More info on the[Erlang docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#consult-1)